# Apache rewrite rule only working when rewriting root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an apache server running on localhost:8888. The following Virtual Host rule points to my rails application on localhost:3000:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RewriteEngine  on
  RewriteRule    "^/(.*)$"  "http://localhost:3000/$1"  [P]
  ProxyPass        "/ia" "http://localhost:3000"
  ProxyPassReverse "/ia" "http://localhost:3000"
  ServerName localhost:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine but the re-write rule is sending all requests to the rails server and I only want it to rewrite requests following http://localhost:8888/ia/*. I have tried:

```
RewriteRule    "^/ia/(.*)$"  "http://localhost:3000/$1"  [P]
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteRule    "^\/ia\/(.*)$"  "http://localhost:3000/$1"  [P]
```

but this doesn't seem to re-write anything. Essentially, without the rewrite rule, if I go to http://localhost:8888/ia none of the images/css will render because it's not re-writing links to localhost:3000. What am I missing?